# Finding infinite sum

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, markov-chains

I am really stuck as to how I find this infinite sum:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \left[ 1-p(1-q)^{n-1} \right]$$

The restrictions on $p$ and $q$ is that they both must be less than $1$ but greater than $0$, as this is the context of a probability question. The context is trying to find a stationary distribution, and one of the equations I end up with is: 
$$2\pi_1 + \pi_1\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left[ 1-p(1-q)^{n-1} \right] = 1$$

Thank you.

Comment: You should use parentheses to clarify your expressions.  $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 1=\infty = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}[1-p(1-q)^{n-1}] \neq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(1-p)(1-q)^{n-1}$$

Comment: Are $p$ and $q$ related in any way? What is the Markov chain you consider?

Comment: Clarify the parenthesis first. If the expression is something like this $(1-p)(1-q)^{n-1}$, then this is a simple G.P. problem. What do you need help for, if that is the case?

Comment: I added the bracket but honestly I am not sure if this is what the OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

The sum diverges. I'll proove it by the integral criterium.
$$\int_0^\infty1-p(1-q)^{x-1}dx=\left[x-\frac{p(1-q)^{x-1}}{\ln(1-q)}\right]_0^\infty=\infty$$
This integral diverges, so the sum diverges too.